# Command-line: Insert the output from a unix command at a given point in a template file

Tags: templates, unix, command-line, awk, sed

I was looking for a one-liner to replace a matched string in a template file with a base64 string of a file. So in the following template file:

```
# config.template.yaml

is_real: "yes"
project_base64: {base64_string}
file_name: "project.tgz"
```

in one-line replace `{base64_string}` with the output of `base64 -w0 project.tgz`.

I tried using sed as follows:

```bsh
sed s/{base64_string}/`base64 -w0 project.tgz`/ config.template.yaml > config.yaml
```

This worked fine if `project.tgz` is small, but as it's actually several megabytes, I get an error:

```
bash: /bin/sed: Argument list too long
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
is_real: "yes"
project_base64: {base64_string}
file_name: "project.tgz"

$ awk -v b64="$(printf "hello\nworld\n")" '{gsub(/{base64_string}/, b64); print}' file
is_real: "yes"
project_base64: hello
world
file_name: "project.tgz"
```

Replace `printf "hello\nworld\n"` with `base64 -w0 project.tgz`.

Comment: When the content of b64 is long, you get `bash: /usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use awk to store the output of the command in an array, when the command is disguised as a file using `<(command)`, in your case `<(base64 -w0 project.tgz)`.
Next the array can be written when you are processing file2.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0;next}
    /^project_base64:/ { printf "project_base64:";
                         for (i=1; i <= length(a); i++) { print a[i] };
                         next
                       }
    {print}' <(base64 -w0 project.tgz) config.template.yaml
```

When the command to be inserted only has one line, you do not need a loop for inserting the array. The option `-w0` allows the next simplification:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next}
    /^project_base64:/ { print "project_base64:" a[1];
                         next
                       }
    {print}' <(base64 -w0 project.tgz) config.template.yaml
```

When you want to use `sed`, make sure that `base64` is executed by `sed`:

```
sed 's/{base64_string}/printf "%s" "&";base64 -w0 project.tgz/e' config.template.yaml
```

Comment: the for loop is not needed.. just print a[1] ````awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0;next} /^project_base64:/ { printf "project_base64:"; print a[1] ;next }  {print}' <(base64 -w0 project.tgz) config.template.yaml```` worked for me

Comment: @stack0114106 You are right, I didn't look at option `-w0` suppressing linewrap.

Answer (score 0):

With Perl,

```
$ cat config.template.yaml
is_real: "yes"
project_base64: {base64_string}
file_name: "project.tgz"

$  perl -pe ' s/\{base64_string\}/qx(base64 -w0 project.tgz)/ge if /project_base64/ ' config.template.yaml
is_real: "yes"
project_base64: MTIzCg==
file_name: "project.tgz"
```

Answer (score -3):

The solution I ended up going with is using `awk`, and since nobody understands `awk` I thought I'd post it here in case anyone else has a similar problem:

```bsh
awk '{"base64 -w0 project.tgz"|getline b64; gsub("{base64_string}", b64); print}' config.template.yaml > config.yaml
```

## Explanation

[`awk`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) is a hideously complicated command-line tool, which runs a little program against each line of a file. The program is enclosed between curly braces: `awk '{<your program here>}' <filename>`.

I realised that the `gsub` function was my solution fairly quickly. The part that took me the most time was working out how to pass the output of a bash command to `gsub`. It turns out `getline` was my solution. If you do `"<some bash command>"|getline <var_name>` it will store the first line of the command output in that variable name.

So what the above line does for each line of `config.template.yaml`:

- Save the output of `base64 -w0 project.tgz` in the variable `b64`
- Run `gsub({base64_string}, b64)` on the line, to replace all occurrences of `{base64_string}` with the output of `base64 -w0 project.tgz`
- Print the output to STDOUT

I then redirect all the output to a new file `config.yaml` and voila!

Comment: "and since nobody understands `awk`..."? Really? What leads you to that conclusion? I suspect there is quite sufficient evidence to the contrary...

Comment: awk couldn't be much simpler. You do not understand it, thousands do. The posted "solution" above is absurdly complicated and error-prone.

Comment: @Robin, you certainly do not want to calculate the base64 value for every line in the template. Please carefully read Ed Morton's answer.